# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm getting the following error when trying to insert values in the table:

> INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BookingCustomer_Booking". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\B00711882\SOURCE\WORKSPACES\SAILAWAY\SAILAWAY FINAL\SAILAWAYV2\SAILAWAYV2\APP_DATA\SAILAWAY.MDF", table "dbo.Booking", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.

My insert statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[inserBookingCustomer]
    @customerID INT,
    @bookingID INT
AS
    INSERT INTO BookingCustomer (CustomerID, BookingID)
    VALUES (@customerID, @bookingID)

    RETURN 0
```

Table definitions:

`Booking`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking] 
(
    [ID]        INT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CharterID] INT   NOT NULL,
    [TotalCost] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] DATE  NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]   DATE  NOT NULL,
    [TotalDays] INT   NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Booking] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_CharterID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CharterID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Charter] ([ID])
);
```

`BookingCustomer` (where information should be inserted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookingCustomer] 
(
    [ID]         INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BookingID]  INT NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_BookingCustomer] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BookingCustomer_Booking] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([BookingID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Booking] ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BookingCustomer_Customer] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID])
);
```

This is an ASP.Net application.

Edit: My c# code: https://pastebin.com/5a8seRh4

Comment: You have values of bookid and customerid already exists in the database?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, they already exist.

Comment: The error is saying that there is no ID in Booking table that matches the BookingID you are inserting into BookingCustomer.

Comment: Tried to execute stored procedure directly on database using the same values of customerid and bookingid? Is it inserting value there?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, it inserts the values, which I found strange.

Comment: That's strange. You need to debug your code and check if value of bookingid is changed before it passed to the stored procedure.

Comment: Check that you are not inserting the values twice.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Might be because of how I'm trying to do it. 

It searches for Charter ID in order to insert the right details to the Booking table, then I try to search for the bookingID that is freshly generated (This is all done in Page Load event in correct sequence). Will it be because it takes time to insert the values and it's trying to read them too fast?

Comment: Without seeing your code of that logic, can't say much.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Just tried to de-bug that and it's not the case. I've also noticed that when to code terminates, it creates a record but then it deletes it because the ID has incremented.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya here is the code on the page: https://pastebin.com/5a8seRh4

Comment: Who's debugging are you sure that `bookingID2` is getting proper value and it is not zero?

Comment: @MrDarkness96 - You should take your code out of pastebin and put it in your question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Just checked, and the bookingID2 is not getting a value, when i run it on its' own, I do get a value.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that was an issue! It wasn't getting any value got it fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you was tried to insert a value that no are inserted before in the Booking table.

You need to insert the book first and next insert the reference of the book with the customer